# Need to override page/meta title on views page

Tags: 7, views, meta-tags

I have installed meta tag modules,then enable the meta:views mudule for meta tags.
After that i have added meta tags from views interface.
Now I need to override these value on the basis of exposed filter dropdown.I mean when i change filter,then meta values should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [hook_metatag_metatags_view_alter](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!metatag!metatag.api.php/function/hook_metatag_metatags_view_alter/7)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_metatag_metatags_view_alter().
 */
 function mymodule_metatag_metatags_view_alter(&$output, $instance, $options) {
   if (isset($_GET['some_filter']) && $_GET['some_filter'] == 'some value') {
     $output['title']['#attached']['metatag_set_preprocess_variable'][0][2] = t('New meta title');
    $output['description']['#attached']['drupal_add_html_head'][0][0]['#value'] = t('New meta description');
   }
 }
```